# macOS in Jenkins batch command is not working

Tags: jenkins, cicd, jenkins-job-builder

I am trying to execute windows batch command in Jenkins from macOS and not succeed, walk through the internet try to find a way how I can create artifact (file) in Jenkins command line with this code `echo Hello World! >> config.txt` from macOS but couldn't succeed, if anyone who had experience and can suggest solution it will be appreciated.

**This is the place where I added to command**
[image]

**This is the output of build**
[image]

Comment: Through CMD I could create the file and push there the text

Comment: (Not a Mac  user...) I think you should run "Execute Shell Step", which is Unix, not the Windows CMD.

Comment: @IanW that is also I tried and no succeed, but I run the same command maybe I need to run another command, but in OS cmd this command is works